# XAudio2 create() failed

Tags: c++, windows, directx, xaudio2

When I try to use XAudio2 it already fails at the XAudio2Create(...) function. (INITIALIZE returns at this line: `if (FAILED(hr)) return false;` I don't know why and google only tells me to install the directx redistributable, which I did but nothing changed... Any Ideas?

This is basicly code from MSDN:

```
IXAudio2* pXAudio2 = NULL;

bool INITIALIZE()
{
    HRESULT hr = XAudio2Create(&pXAudio2, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return false;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I tried this but none of those Error-Codes seem to match:

```
HRESULT hr = XAudio2Create(&pXAudio2, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR);
std::cout << "hresult: " << hr << std::endl;
if (hr == XAUDIO2_E_DEVICE_INVALIDATED) std::cout << "XAUDIO2_E_DEVICE_INVALIDATED";
if (hr == XAUDIO2_E_INVALID_CALL) std::cout << "XAUDIO2_E_INVALID_CALL";
if (hr == XAUDIO2_E_XAPO_CREATION_FAILED) std::cout << "XAUDIO2_E_XAPO_CREATION_FAILED";
if (hr == XAUDIO2_E_XMA_DECODER_ERROR) std::cout << "XAUDIO2_E_XMA_DECODER_ERROR";
if (hr == S_OK) std::cout << "S_OK";
```

Output:

```
hresult: -2147221008
```

Comment: Without a complete testcase (what is `pXAudio2`? Is it a valid `IXAudio2` object? Are you sure? Why?) we cannot help further.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind Google: use [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.xaudio2.xaudio2create%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Returns `S_OK` if successful, an error code otherwise. See [XAudio2 Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee419234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for descriptions of XAudio2 specific error codes.

Simply check that error code to find out what's going on.

Comment: But my HRESULT is not equal to any of those Error Codes... (see edited question). Does it make a difference whether I use the `XAudio2.h` from DirectX SDK June 2010 or the `xaudio2.h` from Windows8 SDK!? (Im running Windows7)

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it...
I forgot the `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);` before the code.
Now it returns `S_OK`!